# How can I rotate a mesh by 90 degrees in ThreeJS?

Tags: javascript, matrix, 3d, rotation, three.js

I have a mesh that I want to rotate by 90 degrees inside Three JS. 
Here is the image of the current situation:
[image]

I want the selected mesh to be rotated parallelly to the large mesh.
I have tried rotating the matrix like this:

```
matrix =   new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(1.57)
```

But the mesh goes into strange rotations. Is there any easier way to rotate it by 90 degrees ?

Comment: object.rotation.y = THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 );

Answer (score 96):

The threejs rotation uses Radians (as you might know)

you can use this

```js
mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
```

or

```js
mesh.rotation.set(new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, Math.PI / 2));
```

Comment: Worked great. Thanks!

Comment: `mesh.rotation.set(new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, Math.PI / 2));` don't work on r96. use `setFromVector3` instead of `set`

Comment: `mesh.rotation.set(0, 0, Math.PI / 2)` is Ok with r101. Using `rotation.set()` with a Vector3 gives `NaN` values in properties `matrix` and `matrixWorld` which makes your object disappear from the scene, showing nothing in console.

Comment: That is because `mesh.rotation` is a `THREE.Euler` and not a `THREE.Vector3`, this is a different object type.

Answer (score 32):

You can rotate an object by using this function:

```
function rotateObject(object, degreeX=0, degreeY=0, degreeZ=0) {
   object.rotateX(THREE.Math.degToRad(degreeX));
   object.rotateY(THREE.Math.degToRad(degreeY));
   object.rotateZ(THREE.Math.degToRad(degreeZ));
}

// usage:
rotateObject(myPlane, 40, 30, 20);
```

Comment: NOT good  
`THREE.Math.degToRad()` or `THREE.Math.radToDeg()`

Comment: That is inefficient as it will trigger 3 matrix multiplications instead of one. Would be ok if you want to interact with a single mesh, for example manipulation by user but not recommended if you call that repeatedly for eg an animation ...

Answer (score 12):

Let's say `meshToRotate` needs to be rotated by 90 degrees in X axis. Then do the following.

```
var meshToRotate = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

//Rotating mesh by 90 degree in X axis.     
meshToRotate.rotateX( Math.PI / 2 );
```

Answer (score 6):

For X axis you can use method rotateX()

```
mesh.rotateX(Math.PI / 180 * 90)
```

For example: is a 1º deg step

```
Math.PI / 180 = 0.17453292519943295
```

Result 90º is

```
0.17453292519943295 * 90 = 1.5707963267948966
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles

```
rotateX()
rotateY()
rotateZ()
```

Answer (score 5):

Tested on r96, you can also use

```
mesh.rotation.setFromVector3(new THREE.Vector3( Math.PI / 2, 0, 0));
```

Comment: `mesh.rotation.set( Math.PI / 2, 0, 0 );`

Comment: mesh.updateMatrixWorld() needs to be called if autoUpdate is not enabled

Answer (score 4):

Convert your angle to radian value:

```
let radian = 2 * Math.PI * (p_angle / 360); //p_angle = your angle, example; 90 or 12, whatever angle
```

Comment: As you are new to the StackOverflow community. Please format the code part of your answer as per the guidelines. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer  That would improve the readability.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to set a quaternion of the mesh

```
mesh.quaternion.set(0, Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
```

Or even simpler without overriding other values

```
mesh.quaternion.y = Math.PI / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I use **quaternions to rotate the objects.**

```
   function rotate( object, deg, axis ) 
  {
      // axis is a THREE.Vector3
      var q = new THREE.Quaternion();
       q.setFromAxisAngle(axis, THREE.MathUtils.degToRad( deg ) ); // we need to use radians
       q.normalize();
       object.quaternion.multiply( q );
   }
```

So to *rotate object by 90 degrees* on the Z axis we would call it like

```
rotate( myMesh, 90, new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );
```

Or if you want to **rotate it gradualy over time** you can use slerp. And increase the progress value that goes from 0 to 1.

```
function rotateSlerp( object, deg, axis, progress )
{
    var q = new THREE.Quaternion();
    q.setFromAxisAngle( axis, THREE.MathUtils.degToRad( deg ) );
    q.normalize();
    object.quaternion.slerp( q, progress );
}
```

To use it, you would call

```
let progress = 0;

function loop()
{
  progress += 0.05;
  rotateSlerp( myMesh, 90, new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1), progress );
  requestAnimationFrame( loop );
}
```