# how to rotate around x axis and then y axis using quaternions

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to apply rotation to an object around it's x axis 90 degrees first, and then around it's y axis 90 degrees. How can I do that in three.js?

I tried

```
mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI * 0.5;
mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI * 0.5;
```

but it doesn't rotate as I wanted.

Comment: `but it doesn't rotate as I wanted` what was expected, what was the actual? Looks like you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30154137/1790644) to maybe rotate two axies at once?

Comment: think of axises like global don't change, i want to rotate the object around x axis, and then around y axis. It's pretty easy to visualize. But I guess rotating first on x axis changes it's local axises so i can't rotate around global y axis again.

Comment: Is using quaternions a requirement? Is the mesh rotated to begin with? Make sure your question is clear as to _global_ or _local_ axes. Study the `Object3D` methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rotate a 3D object on axis three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060734/how-to-rotate-a-3d-object-on-axis-three-js)

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve like this,

```
mesh.rotateX(Math.PI * 0.5);
mesh.rotateY(Math.PI * 0.5);
```